# Requery a form based on current record in another form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a form that has two subforms; AvailablePublicFolderUsersSubform and RelatedSharedMailboxSubform.

For the current record on AvailablePublicFolderUsersSubform, I want to requery  form RelatedSharedMailboxSubform based on the value of column PrimarySmtpAddress in AvailablePublicFolderUsersSubform.

When I open the main form, I get the following error within form AvailablePublicFolderUsersSubform:

[image]

Any suggestions to make the proper RecordSource change and eliminate the error is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably your **subform control** has a different name than `RelatedSharedMailboxSubform`. Check in the main form properties.

Comment: Or if the code runs in the other subform, you need `Me.Parent.RelatedSharedMailboxSubform.` etc.

Comment: [Forms: Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

Comment: The name of the control is correct, not misspelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code runs in another subform, `AvailablePublicFolderUsersSubform`, you need to "navigate" from there:

- up (to the main form),
- sideways (to the other subform),
- down (form + properties of subform)

which translates to

```
Me.Parent.RelatedSharedMailboxSubform.Form.RecordSource
```

Note: after setting `.RecordSource` you don't need `.Requery`, this is done automatically.